# Defining the model function of a non linear mixed effects model as a ODE system in Matlab nlmefit

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, mixed-models

I am learning non linear mixed effects models and I am trying to estimate parameters of a ODE system using that. I have tried the Matlab example on nonlinear mixed effects on [using `nlmefit`](https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/mixed-effects-models-using-nlmefit-and-nlmefitsa.html)

Based on the example in that page, I want to change the code so that the model parameters of the following system ($\lambda,\rho,\eta,\delta,c$) can be found.
[image]

(As an attempt, I am fitting to the same data found in Matlab example from `load indomethacin` .So, the data consists of how the drug concentration changes in 6 subjects measured over a time period of 8 hours and in my code I am supposing the `concentration` is given by (T_u+T_v).  I want to fit the model by solving the system using `ode45`, rather than taking the analytical solution of T_u+T_v.

This is the code that I have written,

```
clear
close all
load indomethacin

nlme_model = @(PHI,t)virusModel(PHI,time(1:11),[0.05,0,0]);

phi0 = [0.09 0.06212 0.02588 0.08414 0.02];

[phi,PSI,stats] = nlmefit(time,concentration,subject, ...
[],nlme_model,phi0)

PHI = repmat(phi,1,6) + ... % Fixed effects
[b(1,:);b(2,:);b(3,:);b(4,:);b(5,:)]; % Random effects
RES = zeros(11,6); % Residuals
colors = 'rygcbm';
%plotting the results
for I = 1:6

fitted_model = virusModel([PHI(1,I),PHI(2,I),PHI(3,I),PHI(4,I),PHI(5,I)],time(1:11),[0.05,0,0]);
tI = time(subject == I);
cI = concentration(subject == I);
RES(:,I) = cI - fitted_model(tI);
subplot(2,3,I)
scatter(tI,cI,20,colors(I),'filled')
hold on
plot(tI,fitted_model(tI),'Color',colors(I))
axis([0 8 0 3.5])
xlabel('Time (hours)')
ylabel('Concentration (mcg/ml)')
legend(num2str(I),'Subject')
end
figure(2)
normplot(RES(:))
```

and the model function,

```
function output= virusModel(PHI,thours,initialCond)

   [~,values] = ode45(@virusEquations,thours,initialCond);

    function s=virusEquations(t,y)

    s=zeros(3,1);

    s(1)=PHI(:,1)-PHI(:,2).*y(1)-PHI(:,3).*y(1).*y(3);%differential equaiton for T_u
    s(2)=PHI(:,3).*y(1)*y(3)-PHI(:,4).*y(2);%differential equaiton for T_i
    s(3)=PHI(:,4).*y(2)-PHI(:,5)*y(3);%differential equaiton for V

    end
output=values(:,1)+values(:,2);
end
```

I am not sure if this is written corretly as I get an error as

```
Error using nlmefit>LMfit (line 1848)
After the initial refinement of the fixed effects with the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm some columns of the Jacobian are
effectively zero at BETA0, indicating that the model is insensitive to some of its parameters.  That may be because those
parameters are not present in the model, or otherwise do not affect the predicted values.  It may also be due to numerical
underflow in the model function, which can sometimes be avoided by choosing better initial parameter values, or by rescaling or
recentering.
```

1. Can someone please let me know if I am calling the ode system correctly and implementing the mixed effects correctly?
2. Also, I want to know how I can pass the initial conditions to the
   ode system. Is it possible to     specify specific initial conditions for each of the subjects?